# I'm trying to match all fractions in a string, but using my regular expression I get this error

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match all fractions in a string, returning fraction, numerator and denominator.

This is an example of input:

```
3/4 cup whole milk
```

I would like to get 3/4, 3 and 4 as output.

Here is the regular expression I'm using:

```
/(?<Fraction>(?<FracNum>\d*)\/(?<FracDem>\d*))/g
```

I tested this regular expression in an online tester and everything looks fine, but when I run it in javascript I get the following error:

```
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<Fraction>(?<FracNum>\d*)\/(?<FracDem>\d*))/: Invalid group**
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and ouput?

Comment: I've updated the post with an example of input and output. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Named sub-patterns are not supported in JavaScript.

This should work:

```
/((\d*)\/(\d*))/g
```

though you might want `+` instead of `*`. The whole fraction will be the first group, the numerator the second, and the denominator the third.

If you want to do something with each fraction, one nice way to do that is this:

```
someString.replace(/((\d*)\/(\d*))/g, function(_, fraction, numerator, denominator) {
  doSomething(fraction, numerator, denominator);
});
```

Comment: So can I use something specific to return those matches?

Comment: I edited the answer a little; I'm not sure exactly what it is you want to do with the matched fraction strings.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was trying to do. I got a function that is multiplying the fraction and replacing it in the main string. Thanks a lot

Comment: In case I'm also running this regular expression /[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?/g, can I find a way to prevent it from selecting fractions so it doesn't return matches that I've been previously returned with the one you provided?

Comment: @user1209359 you could change your second regex to not match fractions and run it first.

Comment: @user1209359 You could add `(?!\/\d)` to the end of the "plain number" regex - that would prevent it from matching a number followed by a "/" and a digit. I'm not sure exactly how you'd prevent matching denominators with that however ...